# More than 5000 datapoints

Tags: thingsboard

Completely new here and evaluating Thingsboard to monitor an international collections of hundreds of Particle devices deployed in the gas and fuel industry.

How can I set the data point limit in graphing to a number higher than 5000?

Or is there a way to create on-going strip charts of uninterrupted data?  We are plotting pressure values taken in 5 second intervals the seemingly arbitrary 5000 point limit runs out pretty quickly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a setting in the `thingsboard.yml`:

```
# Dashboard parameters
dashboard:
  # Maximum allowed datapoints fetched by widgets
  max_datapoints_limit: "${DASHBOARD_MAX_DATAPOINTS_LIMIT:50000}"
```

Increase the value (`50000` at my end) to increase the limit.
Don't forget to restart the thingsboard service.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the slider to select the max quantity of points, use the text box next ot it.

[image]